# Changing speechText in the LaunchRequestHandler breaks Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am not entirely sure if I'm doing something incorrectly or I've encountered a bug. Anyways, I created a skill. Going to the "Test" tab, I open said skill and get a standard default invocation message,

> Welcome, you can say Hi or Help. Which would you like to try?

Everything good so far. My lambda function is as follows:

```
// This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK (v2).
// Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
// session persistence, api calls, and more.
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Welcome, you can say Hello or Help. Which would you like to try?';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Hello World!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'You can say hello to me! How can I help?';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
                || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Goodbye!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        // Any cleanup logic goes here.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
    }
};

// The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
// It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
// for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
// handler chain below.
const IntentReflectorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const intentName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name;
        const speechText = `You just triggered ${intentName}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
// stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
// the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${error.message}`);
        const speechText = `Sorry, I couldn't understand what you said. Please try again.`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// This handler acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
// payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
// defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        HelloWorldIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler) // make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers
    .addErrorHandlers(
        ErrorHandler)
    .lambda();
```

Now here's where it gets weird. Changing the speechText in the invocation handler (even slightly) and there's a huge issue. The skill is unable to start. Here is the slightly updated Lambda function:

```
// This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK (v2).
// Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
// session persistence, api calls, and more.
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Welcome, you can say Hi or Help. Which would you like to try?';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Hello World!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'You can say hello to me! How can I help?';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
                || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Goodbye!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        // Any cleanup logic goes here.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
    }
};

// The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
// It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
// for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
// handler chain below.
const IntentReflectorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const intentName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name;
        const speechText = `You just triggered ${intentName}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
// stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
// the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${error.message}`);
        const speechText = `Sorry, I couldn't understand what you said. Please try again.`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// This handler acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
// payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
// defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        HelloWorldIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler) // make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers
    .addErrorHandlers(
        ErrorHandler)
    .lambda();
```

Comment: Can you make it clearer which part you have changed? Also, do you have any error messages (either from local console or Cloud Watch logs)?

Comment: @che.armstrong he only changed the speechText value from saying "hello" to saying "hi". At least that's what I noticed. Besides that, I see no noticeable changes.